# angular directive for each value in parent array keep in sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a parent object containing an array and for each value I render a directive passing in the value via an isolate scope. For this simple demo I just add the object to a controller:

```
  $scope.schedule = {
    __type: "Fixed",
    ids: [101, 102, 103]
  }
})
```

And the directive:

```
    app.directive('picker', function() {

  return {
      scope:{
        import: '='
      },
      template:'<input ng-model="import" >'
  }
});
```

The html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in schedule.ids">
    <picker import="i"></picker>  Bind: {{i}}
  </div>
```

My real world issue is I have a datepicker directive that needs to be reusable so for each of the datepickers rendered, I'd like the underlying / original array to stay in sync as the values are changed. Am I going about this wrongly?

As you can see in the fiddle my rendered directives stay in sync with their isolate scope values but the underlying array they came form does not, plunk below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Nt9QwiBmlaW3PKPo8XRN?p=info

Thanks

Comment: Do you have array of primitives (like in your demo) or objects? Because it makes a big difference and requires different approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the elements of array are primitives you need to reference the actual array

```
<div ng-repeat="i in schedule.ids track by $index">
    <picker import="schedule.ids[$index]"></picker>  Bind: {{i}}
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6eUPPhId4xOuQmlfyZkR?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: ahh so primitives are copied by value i.e. the directives are getting copies of the array values and the track by syntax makes the directives receive by reference? I should of known that :D many thanks

Comment: Not quite. track by just helps with digest issues and improves performance. Without it the dom repaints every key stroke and input loses focus. It's the `import` reference that is the part allowing the object to have 2 way binding

Comment: I see, so the schedule.ids [ $index] part creates a referential link where schedule.ids[i] would pass a copy of the value?

Answer (score 1):

Use reference, not value, as angular will try to shallow copy that object

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, value) in schedule.ids track by $index">
    <picker import="schedule.ids[index]"></picker>  Bind: {{value}}
</div>
```

`import="i"` is shallow copy of *schedule.ids*, `import="schedule.ids[index]"` is reference of *schedule.ids*,

Working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/QX4Siu4xsJ6poQyy7Ljb?p=preview

Comment: Use `track by` to avoid problems with cursor when editing. Try typing more than one character in an input